# Getting related data through object_2_object table with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have an `Pet` object, which belongs to a `Species` through `SpeciesToPet`.

I have the following definitions with Sequelize.

```
const Pet = sequelize.define(`pet`, {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  }
  ...
})

const SpeciesToPet = sequelize.define(`speciesToPet`, {
  speciesId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  petId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  }
})

const Species = sequelize.define(`species`, {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  }
})
```

Now, with `Pet.belongsToMany(Species, { as: 'species', through: SpeciesToPet,foreignKey: 'petId', otherKey: 'speciesId' })` I can get the `Species` which the `Pet` belongs to, but I want to be able to get the `Pet`s in the same `Species`.

How can I define a relationship to obtain those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just define `Species->Pet` relation:

```
Species.belongsToMany(Pet, { as: 'pets', through: SpeciesToPet});
```